# Shield UI XML Inline Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, grid, shieldui

I do not understand a lot of Shield UI. Documentation is very vague to me. What I'd like to do is have the table that is produced with the code below to become editable. I've tried about everything and feel I am close but no avail. Could someone please guide me? Also, I've taken several looks at their documentation as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(document).ready(function()) {
      $("#grid").shieldGrid({
        dataSource: {
          remote: {
            read: g,
            modify: {
              url: "xml/smt-schedule.xml"
            },


          },
          /*End remote */

          schema: {
            type: "xml",
            data: "ss_schedule",
            fields: {
              Id: {
                path: "ss_id._text"
              },
              Part_Num: {
                path: "ss_part_num._text"
              },
              ROHS: {
                path: "ss_rohs._text"
              },
              Wave_SS: {
                path: "ss_wave_ss._text"
              },
              WO: {
                path: "ss_wo._text"
              },
              Quantity: {
                path: "ss_qty._text"
              },
              Duration: {
                path: "ss_duration._text"
              },
              Start_Date: {
                path: "ss_wo_start._text"
              },
              Total_Time: {
                path: "ss_total_time._text"
              },
              Days: {
                path: "ss_est_days._text"
              },
              Run_Date: {
                path: "ss_est_run_date._text"
              },
              Pulled: {
                path: "ss_pulled._text"
              },
              Prep: {
                path: "ss_prep._text"
              },
              SMT: {
                path: "ss_smt._text"
              },
              Notes: {
                path: "ss_notes._text"
              }
            },

          },
          /* Line 48 Schema */

        },

        /*Begin Code for paging */
        paging: {
          pageSize: 30,
          pageLinksCount: 10,
          messages: {
            infoBarTemplate: "From {0} to {1} items of a total of {2}",
            firstTooltip: "First page",
            previousTooltip: "Previous page",
            nextTooltip: "Next page",
            lastTooltip: "Last page"
          }
        },
        /*End of paging start line 75*/

        /*End Code for paging */

        rowHover: false,
        columns: [{
            field: "Id",
            width: "20px",
            editable: false
          }, {
            field: "Part_Num",
            width: "100px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "ROHS",
            width: "80px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Wave_SS",
            title: "Wave/SS",
            width: "80px"
          }, {
            field: "WO",
            width: "60px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Quantity",
            width: "80px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Duration",
            width: "80px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Start_Date",
            title: "Start Date",
            width: "80px",
            type: Date,
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Total_Time",
            title: "Total Time",
            width: "80px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Run_Date",
            title: "Run Date",
            width: "80px",
            type: Date,
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Pulled",
            width: "50px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Prep",
            width: "50px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "SMT",
            width: "50px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            field: "Notes",
            width: "80px",
            editable: true
          }, {
            width: 80,
            title: " ",
            buttons: [{
              commandName: "edit",
              caption: "Edit"
            }, {
              commandName: "delete",
              caption: "Delete"
            }]
          }

        ],
        editing: {
          enabled: true,
          Event: "doubleclick",
          type: "row",
          mode: "inline",


          confirmation: {
            "delete": {
              enabled: true,
              template: function(item) {
                return "Delete work order '" + item.WO + "'?";
              }
            }
          }
        },

        /*--End toolbar--*/


        toolbar: [{
          buttons: [{
            commandName: "pdf",
            caption: '<span class="sui-sprite sui-grid-icon-export-pdf"></span> <span class="sui-grid-button-text">Export to PDF</span>'
          }]
        }],
        exportOptions: {
          proxy: "/filesaver/save",
          pdf: {
            fileName: "smt-schedule-report.pdf",
            author: "Dynalab, Inc.",
            size: "a4",
            orientation: "landscape",
            fontSize: 10,
            margins: {
              left: 40
            }

          } /*End pdf */


        },
        /*End expportOptions */
        toolbar: [{
          buttons: [{
            commandName: "insert",
            caption: "Add Record"
          }],
          position: "top"
        }]

      });
      /* Begin search by typing */
      var dataSource = $("#grid").swidget().dataSource,
        input = $("#filterbox input"),
        timeout,
        value;
      input.on("keydown", function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          value = input.val();
          if (value) {
            dataSource.filter = {
              or: [{
                  path: "Part_Num",
                  filter: "contains",
                  value: value
                }, {
                  path: "WO",
                  filter: "contains",
                  value: value
                }

              ]
            };
          } else {
            dataSource.filter = null;
          }
          dataSource.read();
        }, 300);

        /*End search by typing */
      });
    }
  }); /*End document.ready */
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can enable editing by using [this setting](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/editing) (and its child properties).

Then you should override the `create`, `update` and `remove` settings under `remote.modify`, as shown in [this example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-restful-web-service). You can put some callback functions there, that will be called by the Grid whenever a similar action is taken. Those functions will normally contain code that calls your server-side to update your data on a persistent location.

Comment: So then do I need to place editable: true in the column fields then? Also, what would I use for the url? My file(s) are located at xml/filename.xml

Comment: Editable for a column is true by default, so no need to explicitly set it to true. And you should use the relative or absolute URL of your resources, containing the XML (more info - http://www.w3.org/Addressing).

Comment: ok, so I have managed to get the fields to be editable. I am using a JSON file now. Seems to be easier. However, now I get a Transport Error: Method Not Allowed when updating, deleting or adding a new record. I am using the full url path which is at this moment http://localhost/DarkAdmin/

Comment: Method Not Allowed is an HTTP error - you need to check your server-side code.